# I got stuck with C# while creating a player class

Tags: c#

hello I coded a little player script
I tried fixing it for hours and I just cant figure it out

```
namespace PlayerManager {
    public class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ClassNum { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public int Intel { get; set; }
        public int Agi { get; set; }
        public int Str { get; set; }
        public int Cha { get; set; }
        public int MaxHealth { get; set; }
        public int Armor { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public int Balance { get; set; }
        public double Health { get; set; }
        public double Exp { get; set; }

        public Player(string name, int classnum, string classname, int intel, int agi, int str, int cha, int maxhealth, int armor, int level, int balance, double health, double exp) {
            Name = name;
            ClassNum = classnum;
            ClassName = classname;
            Intel = intel;
            Agi = agi;
            Str= str;
            Cha = cha;
            MaxHealth = maxhealth;
            Armor = armor;
            Level = level;
            Balance = balance;
            Health = health;
            Exp = exp;
        }

        void Stats(){}

        void createPlayer()
        {
            var P1 = new Player(Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Heros Name :");
            P1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose your heros class : (1.Rouge/2.Fighter/3.Wizard)");
            P1.ClassNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (P1.ClassNum == 1) 
            {
                P1.ClassName = "Rouge";
                P1.Intel = 2;
                P1.Agi = 4;
                P1.Str = 3;
                P1.Cha = 1;
                P1.MaxHealth = 12;
                P1.Armor = 2;
            }
            else if (P1.ClassNum == 2)
            {
                P1.ClassName = "Fighter";
                P1.Intel = 1;
                P1.Agi = 2;
                P1.Str = 5;
                P1.Cha = 2;
                P1.MaxHealth = 15;
                P1.Armor = 3;
            }
            else if (P1.ClassNum == 3)
            {
                P1.ClassName = "Wizard";
                P1.Intel = 4;
                P1.Agi = 2;
                P1.Str = 1;
                P1.Cha = 3;
                P1.MaxHealth = 12;
                P1.Armor = 2;
            }

            P1.Level = 0;
            P1.Balance = 0;
            P1.Health = P1.MaxHealth;
            P1.Exp = 0.0;

            Console.WriteLine("your heros name is : " + P1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("your heros class is : " + P1.ClassName);
            Console.WriteLine("hes intel is : " + P1.Intel);
            Console.WriteLine("hes strenght is : " + P1.Str);
            Console.WriteLine("hes charisma is : " + P1.Cha);
            Console.WriteLine("he got max health of : " + P1.MaxHealth);
            Console.WriteLine("he got a armor that can block : " + P1.Armor);
            Console.WriteLine("he currently is level : " + P1.Level);
            Console.WriteLine("he got : " + P1.Balance + " gold coins");
            Console.WriteLine("and he got : " + P1.Health + " health points");
            Console.WriteLine("Expiriance : " + P1.Exp);

            void Main()
        {

            createPlayer();

        }

        }

        void takeDamage(int eDamage, int pHealth)
        {
            pHealth = pHealth - eDamage;
        }

        void giveDamage(int pDamage, int eHealth)
        {
            eHealth = eHealth - pDamage;
        }

        void healPlayer(int heal, int pHealth)
        {
            pHealth = pHealth + heal;
        }

        void healEnemy(int eHeal, int eHealth)
        {
            eHealth = eHealth + eHeal;
        }

        void gainExp(double expA, double pExp)
        {
            pExp = pExp + expA;

            Console.WriteLine(pExp + " exp Gained");
        }

        void gainLevel(int pLevel)
        {
            pLevel = pLevel + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

there are some not needed { and } I was just playing with every problem the console showed me and I really don't know what to do any more
I have a player class and its properties
then some unfinished functions but the main problem the console shows me right now is that the main needs to be in the public class

Comment: Your question title should be a summary of the problem you face with your code. Your current title tells us nothing of your problem. Everybody is posting questions here because they are stuck.

Comment: *I got lots of errors* - not mentioning the exact text of any of them is the single biggest reason your question is unanswerable. If we were your mechanic, you just called us and said "my car is making a noise".. We need specific detail to work off, not a paraphrase of it (Your paraphrase "main needs to be in the public class" cannot be accurate; your Main *is* in a public class, and it doesn't actually need to be - do not paraphrase the compiler's errors)

Comment: `public static main() {...}`

Comment: Better not abbreviate your property names.

Comment: @Tarik C# is not Java, doesn't need to be public either

Comment: Extract the `Player` class to its own file. This will make it easier to distinguish between the members of the `Player` class and the members of the `Program` class and you will get more precise error messages telling you where braces are missing. Currently you have mixed things from the `Player` and the `Program` class, because the `Player` class is not terminated by a `}`. Most C# programmers create one source file per class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> problem the console shows me right now is that the main needs to be in the public class

Actually, I suspect the error message is something like

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Your line of code:

```
void Main()
```

Should minimally read:

```
static void Main()
```

That will mean that the program does now contain a static entry point, but you cannot call `createPlayer` (which is not static), from a static environment.

As written you can only call `createPlayer` on an existing instance of a Player, but you don't *have* an instance, and `createPlayer` creates one, so realistically, `createPlayer` needs to be static too to escape the chicken-and-egg situation

Note the next confusing thing you'll hit is that the very first thing createPlayer does is `ReadLine()`, to supply a value for the first argument of the `Player(` constructor, which means your program will sit there with a completely blank black window, waiting for your input. It would perhaps be better to use the pattern found further down, where you print a message, and then do a ReadLine, so the user knows what to do.

Make the line:

```
var P1 = new Player("", 0, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

So you aren't going straight to a ReadLine() and you can get some joy out of your code (as in, it runs and does something)

Then, consider carefully *what you actually need that constructor to be*. We use constructors to ensure that a class cannot be created without the bare minimum set of info it needs to do its work properly. From what is written it seems that the bare minimum is a name and a class, so shorten the constructor:

```
    public Player(string name, int classnum)
    {
        Name = name;
        ClassNum = classnum;
    }
```

And then rework the code to collect answers into temp variables until it has enough info to make a player:

```
    static void createPlayer()
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Heros Name :");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Choose your heros class : (1.Rouge/2.Fighter/3.Wizard)");
        var classNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var p1 = new Player(name, classNum);
```

Next think on that it's perhaps not really the job of something outside <sup>*(I'll come back to this)</sup> the Player to set these parameters:

```
        if (P1.ClassNum == 1)
        {
            P1.ClassName = "Rouge";
            P1.Intel = 2;

         ...
```

They're things the constructor can do because it has enough info to set them up, so put those *inside* the constructor and then take all that `createPlayer` code, which doesn't just create a player but actually is the start of something that runs an entire game script, and put it *outside* the Player class. I would recommend to make another class called Program (it;s conventional) and put both the `static void Main` and the `static void createPlayer` into that class, and have Player as a separate thing because it better separates the concerns of the code: your player is just modelling a game character, it shouldnt be holding the entire battle script too

It means you end up with something like:

```
public class Player
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...more props...
    public double Exp { get; set; }



    public Player(string name, int classnum)
    {
        Name = name;
        ClassNum = classnum;

        if (ClassNum == 1)
        {
            ClassName = "Rouge";
            Intel = 2;
            Agi = 4;
            Str = 3;
            Cha = 1;
            MaxHealth = 12;
            Armor = 2;
        }

        else if (ClassNum == 2)
        {
            ClassName = "Fighter";
            Intel = 1;
            Agi = 2;
            Str = 5;
            Cha = 2;
            MaxHealth = 15;
            Armor = 3;
        }

        else if (ClassNum == 3)
        {
            ClassName = "Wizard";
            Intel = 4;
            Agi = 2;
            Str = 1;
            Cha = 3;
            MaxHealth = 12;
            Armor = 2;
        }

        Level = 0;
        Balance = 0;
        Health = MaxHealth;
        Exp = 0.0;
    }

}

class Program{

    static void RunGameScript()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Heros Name :");
        var name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Choose your heros class : (1.Rouge/2.Fighter/3.Wizard)");
        var classNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var p1 = new Player(name, classNum);

        Console.WriteLine("your heros name is : " + p1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("your heros class is : " + p1.ClassName);
        Console.WriteLine("hes intel is : " + p1.Intel);
        Console.WriteLine("hes strenght is : " + p1.Str);
        Console.WriteLine("hes charisma is : " + p1.Cha);
        Console.WriteLine("he got max health of : " + p1.MaxHealth);
        Console.WriteLine("he got a armor that can block : " + p1.Armor);
        Console.WriteLine("he currently is level : " + p1.Level);
        Console.WriteLine("he got : " + p1.Balance + " gold coins");
        Console.WriteLine("and he got : " + p1.Health + " health points");
        Console.WriteLine("Expiriance : " + p1.Exp);


    }


    static void Main()
    {

        RunGameScript();

    }
}
```

Next you need to attend to those methods:

[image]

The name looks dim because it's never used. The variable on the left hand side of the `=` looks dim because it's a non-op; the value is not subsequently used, and assigning a value to an int passed into a method does nothing to the int value that was supplied outside the method

---

Lastly, and it might seem like a really petty thing, but you'll see the importance of it the more code you read.. In C# we have particular conventions for names of things. All your methods are camelCase, but the convention is PascalCase. Your P1 local variable is init caps, but we name them with camelCase. It means your code should be like:

```
CreatePlayer() 
^

var p1 = new Player(...)
    ^
```

Avoid abbreviations too, especially on public members as other people may one day use them

Comment: when I do that I get another error

Comment: and when I do fix it I cant call the function

Comment: you need to make `createPlayer()` static too: `static void createPlayer()`

Comment: that's not to say you should make *everything* static; you just need to operate inside a static context until you make an object instance, which is what createPlayer does

Comment: @DavePeace I've added some futher advice

Comment: thank you very much for all that good good info it helped a lot and I only read it once I got a couple more times to read it :D but thank you for your time and effort <3

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player p = new Player();
            p.createPlayer();
        }
    }
```

Make Methods as public & add one more default constructor

```
   public class Player
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ClassNum { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public int Intel { get; set; }

    public int Agi { get; set; }

    public int Str { get; set; }

    public int Cha { get; set; }

    public int MaxHealth { get; set; }

    public int Armor { get; set; }

    public int Level { get; set; }

    public int Balance { get; set; }

    public double Health { get; set; }

    public double Exp { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {

    }

    public Player(string name, int classnum, string classname, int intel, int agi, int str, int cha, int maxhealth, int armor, int level, int balance, double health, double exp)
    {
        Name = name;
        ClassNum = classnum;
        ClassName = classname;
        Intel = intel;
        Agi = agi;
        Str = str;
        Cha = cha;
        MaxHealth = maxhealth;
        Armor = armor;
        Level = level;
        Balance = balance;
        Health = health;
        Exp = exp;
    }
    public void Stats() { }
    public void createPlayer()
    {
        var P1 = new Player(Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()), null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0.0);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Your Heros Name :");
        P1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Choose your heros class : (1.Rouge/2.Fighter/3.Wizard)");
        P1.ClassNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (P1.ClassNum == 1)
        {
            P1.ClassName = "Rouge";
            P1.Intel = 2;
            P1.Agi = 4;
            P1.Str = 3;
            P1.Cha = 1;
            P1.MaxHealth = 12;
            P1.Armor = 2;
        }

        else if (P1.ClassNum == 2)
        {
            P1.ClassName = "Fighter";
            P1.Intel = 1;
            P1.Agi = 2;
            P1.Str = 5;
            P1.Cha = 2;
            P1.MaxHealth = 15;
            P1.Armor = 3;
        }

        else if (P1.ClassNum == 3)
        {
            P1.ClassName = "Wizard";
            P1.Intel = 4;
            P1.Agi = 2;
            P1.Str = 1;
            P1.Cha = 3;
            P1.MaxHealth = 12;
            P1.Armor = 2;
        }

        P1.Level = 0;
        P1.Balance = 0;
        P1.Health = P1.MaxHealth;
        P1.Exp = 0.0;

        Console.WriteLine("your heros name is : " + P1.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("your heros class is : " + P1.ClassName);
        Console.WriteLine("hes intel is : " + P1.Intel);
        Console.WriteLine("hes strenght is : " + P1.Str);
        Console.WriteLine("hes charisma is : " + P1.Cha);
        Console.WriteLine("he got max health of : " + P1.MaxHealth);
        Console.WriteLine("he got a armor that can block : " + P1.Armor);
        Console.WriteLine("he currently is level : " + P1.Level);
        Console.WriteLine("he got : " + P1.Balance + " gold coins");
        Console.WriteLine("and he got : " + P1.Health + " health points");
        Console.WriteLine("Expiriance : " + P1.Exp);

        void Main()
        {

            createPlayer();

        }

    }

    void takeDamage(int eDamage, int pHealth)
    {
        pHealth = pHealth - eDamage;
    }

    void giveDamage(int pDamage, int eHealth)
    {
        eHealth = eHealth - pDamage;
    }

    void healPlayer(int heal, int pHealth)
    {
        pHealth = pHealth + heal;
    }

    void healEnemy(int eHeal, int eHealth)
    {
        eHealth = eHealth + eHeal;

    }

    void gainExp(double expA, double pExp)
    {
        pExp = pExp + expA;

        Console.WriteLine(pExp + " exp Gained");

    }

    void gainLevel(int pLevel)
    {
        pLevel = pLevel + 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: how did you fixed it?